# Using the right pins for keypad

Tags: msp430, interface, keypad, energia

I am using **msp430g2553** microcontroller and a **4x4** HC543 keypad. I am using **Energia** IDE.
I have connected the keypad from **pin 2 through 9**.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key){
    Serial.println(key);
  }
}
```

However I am **unable to get an output at the Serial Monitor**. I am especially confused if I am using the right pin configuration.

I have downloaded the Keypad.h library from Arduino website and imported it in Energia. Can this be a problem? Since all the functions (like makeKeymap and getKey) related to Keypad.h are properly colored.

Comment: put `Serial.println("Hello World");` after `Serial.begin(9600);` just to make sure it's not unrelated to your code.

Comment: Also the example at http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad has `if (key != NO_KEY)` rather than `if(key)`

Comment: Did this end up with a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Comment: This is a very limited suggestion, as this will only pivot the table of keys, whereas the OP gets no output at all. Conversely it's considered good manners to supply some reasoning as to why you think it will help, especially on old questions (like this one) where the issue has been open for a long time.

Comment: It also wouldn't make any difference to the lack of anything on the serial monitor. Changing the pins in this way is equivalent to diagonally mirroring the key map.